# jquery addclass seems to add class but no visual effect

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

First of all here is a jsFiddle example of my problem: http://jsfiddle.net/xJtAr/

I got many div-elements on my site and some of them have a class "number" and only one of them has the class "active_question" which should change they grey border from the number-class to a black border. When the user clicks on one of those elements this one shall get the class "active_question" and this class should be removed from the old div with this class.

The script I wrote in jQuery seems to work fine but there is no visual effect as it should be.

I would be very thankful if someone could help me.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You included the `.` in the various jQuery class methods. This is just the CSS selector and not the class.

So instead of `$(this).addClass('.active_question')` you want `$(this).addClass('active_question')`

Edited your fiddle:

http://jsfiddle.net/xJtAr/1/

Comment: I see...I think I shall get some more sleep

Answer (score 0):

Just remove the `.` from `addClass()` and `removeClass()`

from: `.addClass('.yourClass');` to: `.addClass('yourClass');`